# Laravel Controller unable to create view when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

In a simple Laravel 4 testing app when the user clicks 'upload', jQuery sends formdata to the controller

```
var formdata = new FormData(form);
    request.open('post', 'submit');
    request.send(formdata);
```

The controller receives the files and makes an array of images.

```
foreach(Input::file("image") as $image) {

        $imagename = $image->getClientOriginalname();
        $uploadflag = $image->move('public/uploads', $imagename);
        if($uploadflag){

            $uploadedImages[] = $imagename;
        }
    }
return Response::json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'images uploaded successfully', 'images' => $uploadedImages]);
```

Now I want to display the images in a view (show.php) so in the controller:

```
return View::make('show')
                  ->with('uploadedImages', $uploadedImages);
```

show.php just contains a loop:

```
@foreach($uploadedImages as $uploadedImage)

        <div>{{ HTML::image($uploadedImage) }}</div>

        @endforeach
```

but nothing happens - the view doesn't show. There is no error message in the Laravel log file and the Response::json result shows the images are in the array.
Here are the Routes I have tried:

```
Route::post('show', function()
{
    return View::make('show');
});
```

and I've tried

```
Route::get('show', function()
{
    return View::make('show');
});
```

and I've tried

```
Route::post('show', array(
    'as' => 'show',
    'uses' => 'ImageController@upload'
));
```

Without  the jQuery, there is no problem with the controller - return View::make - but now the jQuery handles the upload it doesn't work. I need the jQuery to allow the user to make a final selection of files to upload.
Any and all help most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

if your output file is just "show.php" it will not work, the file must have the extension .blade, like this "show.blade.php".

and don't forget add this file to your "routes" too.

Comment: Hi, I changed it to show.blade.php, but isn't Route::get('show', function() {return View::make('show');));  OK? It's still not working.

Comment: put to return the view only before output the result

Comment: Thanks but no change. The Response Headers show 200 OK and the Chrome Canary DevTools Preview shows the image details correctly positioned on the page but the page doesn't load. I would like to post an image to show you but I need a reputation of 10 first. It seems to me that if the images are in the page code it must be something in Laravel that I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Use string function before your view file like as

```
return  (String) view('Company.allUserAjax',$data)
```

after that your fill will response